# the litany of consequences

Tags: meaning

> The governor of New York, Andrew Cuomo, has declared that “We’re not going to put a dollar figure on human life.” It was meant as a rallying-cry from a courageous man whose state is overwhelmed. **Yet by brushing trade-offs aside, Mr Cuomo was in fact advocating a choice—one that does not begin to reckon with the litany of consequences among his wider community.** It sounds hard-hearted but a dollar figure on life, or at least some way of thinking systematically, is precisely what leaders will need if they are to see their way through the harrowing months to come. As in that hospital ward, trade-offs are unavoidable.

What does this sentence mean?

article link : https://www.economist.com/leaders/2020/04/01/covid-19-presents-stark-choices-between-life-death-and-the-economy

Comment: What *specifically* do you not understand within that long highlighted sentence?

Comment: the litany of consequences

Comment: The writer is criticizing Cuomo for his failure to take into account the "litany of consequences" that will result from choosing human life over the economy.

Comment: A _litany_ is a prayer consisting of a long list of petitions, often recited in a religious procession. Here it's presumably being used to mean the long list of social and economic consequences that will result from the pandemic.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to find that what I fully expected to be *the most common* collocation *(a litany of **excuses**)* didn't even make it into...

Comment: ... [the top ten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+litany+of+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20litany%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20complaints%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20names%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20praise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20other%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20problems%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20reasons%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20litany%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0) words to follow ***litany***.

Comment: As a metaphor, "litany of consequences" is a reach. Since a litany is a list of petitions, as said above, it is an utterance. Consequences are a step away from an utterance, until they've been listed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the one that came to mind not listed is the alliterative "litany of lies."

Comment: thank you all for the help